# Why am I getting null in the console in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want the div to be output in the console but I am getting 'null' in the console.
This is my HTML ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="two_js.js"></script>
    <title>:)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" class="container">
        This is my HTML Body.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript ->

```
let main = document.getElementById('main');
console.log(main);
```

What should I do?

Comment: TL;DR for the above - because your code runs before the element exists

Comment: Because you put your script above your HTML element

Comment: Move your script to a line below `</div>`. It'll work

Answer (score 0):

Put your script tag inside and at the bottom of body tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   
    <title>:)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" class="container">
        This is my HTML Body.
    </div>

<script src="two_js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```